# Functions In An Array & in addition, Using Time Intervals If Possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To Summarize, I am trying to build a game that runs through questions with a timer, but not through a single timer, having each question go for 10 seconds and then reset when the 10 seconds are up. I'm very new to JavaScript so I am completely open to any advice. But I am trying to set these functions within an array and I keep getting an error saying that the function within the array doesn't exist, but it does and i've seen it work before. Am I applying the method wrong? and am I misusing the timer function?

$(document).ready(function(){

```js
var arrayOfQuestions = [
    intro(),
    question1()
]

var time = 100;

function intro(){
    $("#questions").html('<h6>Welcome, In this game, You will be presented with a small portion of a song and your goal is to guess the next couple of lyrics. Good Luck</h6>'); 
}

function question1(){
    console.log("Question 1");
    $("#questions").html('<h2>"Do You Remeber? The..."</h2>');
    var ans1 = $("#pot-ans-1").html("<p>21st Night of September...</p>");
    var ans2 = $("#pot-ans-2").html("<p>The Way...</p>");
    var ans3 = $("#pot-ans-3").html("<p>How the stars stole the night away...</p>");
    var ans4 = $("#pot-ans-4").html("<p>My thoughts are with you...</p>");
};

function timer() {
     
        setTimeout(function() {

            time--; //its a countdown so we are looking for decerements specifically
            
            var secs = Math.floor(time/10);

            var tenths = time % 10;

            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = secs + ":" + tenths;
            
            timer();

            if(secs === -1) {
                
                time = 100;
                $("#timer").html("");
                alert("Next Question"); 

            };

      },100);
}


$(document).ready(function(){ 
    timer();
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfQuestions.length; i++) {
        arrayOfQuestions[i]();
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Louis Pierre Questionaire</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <center><ins>
                        <h1 class="Top">Welcome To Pernell's Trivia!</h1>
                    </ins></center>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <center>
                    <h1 class="under">Complete the song phrase!</h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- <p class="empty space"></p> -->
        <div class="ratio-c-w">
            <center>
                <p class="Correct"></p>
                <p class="Wrong"></p>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <center>
                    <p class="timer" id="timer"></p>
                </center>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">

            </div>
        </div>
       

        <div class="qContainer"> <!--contains both the question and the buttons in an entire div-->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8" id="questions-div">
                    <center>
                        <div id="questions" class="question"></div>
                    </center>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <center>
                        <div id="buttons">
                            <button id="pot-ans-1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
                            <button id="pot-ans-2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
                            <button id="pot-ans-3" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
                            <button id="pot-ans-4" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to:

1. remove the "`()`" statement at the end of the function call during the navigation loop of the array in order to have this `arrayOfQuestions[i];`, I think that the index element you are calling it's already a function and it doesn't need another "`()`" (I tested it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2manrhfx/1/) on JSFiddle and it seems to work)
2. modify the second argument of setTimeout() in `1000` instead of `100` since it expresses milliseconds and I grant you'll have a real 10 seconds timeout (;

Have a nice coding (;

Comment: This worked very well for the array of functions! managed to get it to work but only problem i am having now is that all of the functions run before the timer goes off. Is it because of the way I am calling the functions? I still have it similar to how it is setup in the original submission.